# Extracting 3 channels from Kinect2 color stream

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, kinect, libfreenect2

I am trying to extract 3 channels from an image coming from Kinect2 stream.
So, first I ream the color stream with the pylibfreenect2 package.

```
color = frames["color"]
```

So I have the following shape

```
print(color.asarray().shape) #(1080, 1920, 4)
```

As I understood, 4 is rather the number of bytes per pixel or the alpha-channel. I want the image to have 3 channels (RGB) and have a shape of (1080, 1920, 3).
I tried to do it like:

```
image_c = cv2.cvtColor(c, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
```

But had an error from PIL package:

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

Comment: you use `color` array in the print, but `c` array in the cvtColor. Typo?

Comment: yes, typo, sorry. c -> color

Comment: You are expected to pass an array `color` not `c`. `image_c = cv2.cvtColor(color, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)`.